# Word for "alienity"

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice, synonyms

I need a word that describes something wholly different or strange, and I like the word "alien," which I think serves that purpose. However, I need a different form of the word. Here's an example sentence fragment:

> The planet had a sense of complete alienity.

That's not a real word, I know, but I desperately wish it was. Is there another word I'm overlooking?

Comment: You might wait at least 24 hours before choosing an answer. This gives the whole world/globe  of native English speakers a chance to see your question. And questions with an accepted answer are less likely to receive more answers.

Comment: Please include the research you’ve done. Questions that can be answered using commonly-available references are off-topic.

Comment: I'm using alienity myself. Reason being, it scans. Now and then when the language won't provide the word processor must.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*alienness* - the state of being alien

Source:  [Merriam Webster online dictionary](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/alienness)

Comment: I feel like this one works, and saw it during my pre-question web search. However, it's a mouthful and not really phonetically pleasing to me. I guess I just enjoy saying "AY-lee-EHN-ihtee." I guess I'll have to use this one, though. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

How about [otherness](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/otherness)

the quality or state of being other or different

Answer (score 1):

The planet had a sense of complete alienity.

The planet seemed completely alien.

Why use complicated words when simple ones will do?

Answer (score 0):

*Alienness* denotes the quality of being alien.  The *state* of being *an alien,* however, in US law at least, is denoted by *alienage* (see [Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/alienage#legalDictionary) and [Black's Law Dictionary](https://thelawdictionary.org/alienage/)).